# Algorithm to convert UTF8 4 byte string to a UTF16 string in C

Tags: utf-16, utf8mb4

I have a requirement to convert a UTF8 4 byte string to a UTF16 string in C.
I am not allowed to use any external libraries to support it. I already have a macro defined to support the UTF8 3 byte to UTF16 conversion

```
#define UTF8-3BYTE-TO-UCS16(char1,char2,char3) ((((char1) & 0x0F) << 12) | (((char2) & 0x3F) << 6) | ((char3) & 0x3F))
```

I am looking for a similar implementation for the UTF8 4 byte as well.

Comment: I think your macro should be `#define UTF8_4BYTE_TO_UCS16(char1, char2, char3, char4) ((((char1) & 0x07) << 18) | (((char2) & 0x3F) << 12) | (((char3) & 0x3F) << 6) | ((char4) & 0x3F))`...?

Comment: Your suggestion indeed does it, but the problem here is that a unicode code point derived from a 4-byte UTF-8 sequence might be outside BMP (which I mentioned down in my answer), meaning it can't be represented by a single UTF-16 code unit. So, in those cases the code point has to be represented as a surrogate pair in UTF-16, where each surrogate pair consists of two 16-bit code units. UTF-16 can't directly represent chars beyond U+FFFF with a single 16-bit code unit. @YoushaAleayoub

Comment: A valid 4-byte UTF8 sequence will always be outside the BMP. OP, are you allowed to write two macros to generate the high and low surrogates?

Comment: The requirement is to support 4 byte emoji's..Will that fall outside the BMP? 
@MarkTolonen

Comment: @JInuThomas Yes, always. 4-byte supports code points > U+FFFF.

Comment: Thanks @MarkTolonen. Then I guess i need two macros to generate the high and low surrogates. Can you pls help to write the macros?

Comment: @JInuThomas Check my answer maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Here are separate macros to generate the HI/LO surrogates. Better to use a function so errors can be returned for invalid byte sequences or use an existing library for conversion like ICU.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define UTF8_4BYTE_TO_UNICODE(char1, char2, char3, char4) ((((char1) & 0x07) << 18) | (((char2) & 0x3F) << 12) | (((char3) & 0x3F) << 6) | ((char4) & 0x3F))
#define UNICODE_TO_UTF16_HI(uni) ((((uni) - 0x10000) >> 10) + 0xD800)
#define UNICODE_TO_UTF16_LO(uni) ((((uni) - 0x10000) & 0x3FF) + 0xDC00)

int main()
{
    // U+1F50C ELECTRIC PLUG 
    uint32_t uni = UTF8_4BYTE_TO_UNICODE(0xf0, 0x9f, 0x94, 0x8c);
    uint16_t hi = UNICODE_TO_UTF16_HI(uni);
    uint16_t lo = UNICODE_TO_UTF16_LO(uni);
    printf("%04X %04X\n", hi, lo);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
D83D DD0C
```

References (Wikipedia):

- [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)
- [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)

Comment: @str1ng Note the code was updated and I said it was **better** to use a library, not that OP had to :)  For your answer, declaring variables in the macro means the macro can only be used once in a function or duplicate declarations would occur.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yes, I see that you say it's better because errors and I do totally agree with you, but basically as OP stated he wants it without libraries, you haven't provided code without usage of function, therefore I just followed up on comment, and asked for feedback on my code (certainly not to brag around but rather that I can compare my code up to someone else's), and to get feedback. I can't compare to you in any means as you're Senior dev or Remy where both of you have bunch of experience and I am taking a grasp of surface and I'd like to learn on my mistakes.

Comment: @str1ng I'm not using any functions in the macros.  Are you referring to `printf`?  That's just for display of the macro results.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, yeah obviously I misunderstood this, where I got confused is the part where I missed `#define`'s on conversion of surrogates, and because of the fact that I assumed you'd be using function by a comment before code... Related to the code that I posted, is modifying the macro to accept variables as arguments instead of declaring them internally good approach, I'd assume this way it wouldn't lead to duplicate declaration errors in case it's used multiple times in the same function? Or is there any better way @MarkTolonen

Comment: @str1ng The better way would be to write a function instead of a macro.  It doesn't have to use external libraries but could then return multiple values in output parameters and return errors for invalid sequences.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Gotcha, thanks again for comments!

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 encodes a Unicode char to 1-4 bytes. Basically, a UTF-8 4-Byte sequence structure is as following:

```
11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

where `x` represents a bit of the actual Unicode char.

A UTF-8 4-Byte sequence is translated into UTF-16 as a pair of surrogate chars.

You can extract the Unicode code from the UTF-8 sequence, then check if the codepoint is within the range of BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane), and if it is then you can represent it with a single UTF-16 code unit, but if it's not then you do the calculation of high and low surrogates:

```
#define UTF8_4BYTE_TO_UTF16(char1, char2, char3, char4) \
    uint32_t codePoint = (((char1 & 0x07) << 18) | \
                          ((char2 & 0x3F) << 12) | \
                          ((char3 & 0x3F) << 6)  | \
                          (char4 & 0x3F)); \
    uint16_t highSurrogate, lowSurrogate; \
    if (codePoint <= 0xFFFF) { \
        /* BMP character, can be represented directly in UTF-16 */ \
        highSurrogate = (uint16_t)codePoint; \
    } else { \
        /* Calculate surrogates for non-BMP character */ \
        codePoint -= 0x10000; \
        highSurrogate = (uint16_t)((codePoint >> 10) + 0xD800); \
        lowSurrogate = (uint16_t)((codePoint & 0x3FF) + 0xDC00); \
    } \
```

Keep in mind that this macro is using intermediate 32-bit and 16-bit variables, and that you'll have to be sure that these are declared properly in your function, or you'll have to adjust the macro accordingly.

**UPDATE 1:**
Mark Tolonen actually opened my eyes, I didn't think this through, basically he's right when he said that 4-byte UTF-8 sequence is always representing a code point beyond U+FFFF and thus it always requires surrogate pairs in UTF-16. Therefore the check in the code before was not needed.

```
#define UTF8_4BYTE_TO_UTF16(char1, char2, char3, char4) \
    uint32_t codePoint = (((char1 & 0x07) << 18) | \
                          ((char2 & 0x3F) << 12) | \
                          ((char3 & 0x3F) << 6)  | \
                          (char4 & 0x3F)); \
    uint16_t highSurrogate, lowSurrogate; \
    codePoint -= 0x10000; \
    highSurrogate = (uint16_t)((codePoint >> 10) + 0xD800); \
    lowSurrogate = (uint16_t)((codePoint & 0x3FF) + 0xDC00);
```

Comment: If a 4-byte UTF8 sequence is *not* outside the BMP, then it is an invalid sequence.

Comment: @MarkTolonen You're right, I didn't think this through enough, I just updated the answer, thanks for pointing it out.